# Symfony2 Need to send password to API

Tags: symfony

how do i get the password eneterd via a costum user provider. I found this question:

[Symfony Security / Custom User Provider : How to get the login password within the custom User Provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188391/symfony-security-custom-user-provider-how-to-get-the-login-password-within-t)

Which says i would have to overrise the loadUserByName method, and add the password as a parameter, the issue is that i cannot find the file he overrides:

```
security_listeners.xml
```

Where is this file located?

I found the:

```
$user = $this->userProvider->loadUserByUsername($username);
```

call in the DOAAuthenticationProvider, and i see that the method takes:

```
protected function retrieveUser($username, UsernamePasswordToken $token)
```

as augments, i asume i need to pass the password there, and then pass it to loadUserByName, which calls my costum userprovider method.

Any help on how to achieve this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an AuthenticationHandler on your bundle. and the on successful login fetch the password from the token.

in services.yml:

```
    security.authentication.success_handler:
      class: Wix\UserBundle\EventListener\AuthenticationHandler
      arguments:  ["@security.http_utils", {}]
      tags:
          - { name: 'monolog.logger', channel: 'security' }
```

And sample class:

```
 class AuthenticationHandler extends DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler
 {

/**
 * This is called when an interactive authentication attempt succeeds. This
 * is called by authentication listeners inheriting from
 * AbstractAuthenticationListener.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @param TokenInterface $token
 *
 * @return Response never null
 */
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
{

    $response = new RedirectResponse('/');
    $response->setStatusCode(200);

    return $response;
}
```

}